# Extracting all the changesets in an area path using Python

Tags: python-3.x, tfs, changeset

I am using the TFSAPI in python. I am able to extract all the changesets associated with a work item but if a chnageset is not associated with any work item I am not getting it. Is there any way I can get all the changesets in an area path?

Comment: If the changeset is not linked to a work item how area path is related to this changeset?

Comment: It is possible to check in without associating it to a work item. How do i get those changesets? Even if it is in a specific branch is also fine.

Comment: I know it's possible but there is no relation to area path if you not link a work item. you can get the unlink changesets but without area path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can changesets that not linked to a work item with this code:

```
from tfs import TFSAPI

user="username"
password="password"

# Use DefaultCollection
client = TFSAPI("https://tfs-server-url:8080/tfs/", project="DefaultCollection/ProjectName", user=user, password=password)

# Get changesets from 1000 to 1002
changesets = client.get_changesets(from_=1000, to_=1002)

# Get just a particular changeset
changeset = client.get_changeset(1000)
```

Comment: What if I don't know the from_ and to_ values?